# C# DLNA/UPNP Media Playback

Tags: c#, media, upnp, dlna

I'm trying to stream specific media to dlna/upnp compliant devices. I already found out how to send commands to devices using c#(e.g play, pause, stop etc.).

So, i can play media on a device. However, it's unclear to me how i tell the device *what* media to play. Is there a certain command for this?

I saw the "SetAVTransportURI" command but this takes a uri, i just want to play a video file from a shared directory on my network. How do i tell the device which media to play?

Comment: Hi can you share the code for Detecting available DLNA devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per **UPnP MediaRenderer** spec (it's public, look up at [www.upnp.org](http://www.upnp.org)), **AVTransport** service is expected to take URI scheme `file:` only for **internal** protocol, which is *largely unspecified and device specific* (as written in the spec). In other words, you are allowed to `SetAVTransportURI` with `file:` only for things like "1st track on CD" or "Tuner station X". If you want remote connection, you must use protocol **http-get**, that is URI scheme `http:`. Setting up a simple webserver which will publish your shared directory should do the trick.

For this isolated part of UPnP (that is setting **single**, already **known** media URI, **no browsing** and **no metadata** like video name etc.) you don't need your server to know any special DLNA/UPnP services. As soon as you would like to have better-than-none user experience, look up some full blown UPnP MediaServer. There are some written in C# too.

Answer (score 1):

Check the wikipedia entry for the [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) on Windows.
Does your shared network directory also provide DLNA/UPNP services?
Edit:In case there no UPNP service, you may look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418451/c-sharp-upnp-dnla-media-server-library) question regarding UPNP server functionality.

Comment: i used the file://  tag in the uri, the response from the device: "Resource not found", however, the file is accessible when typed in the adressbar of any internet browser